# Reading multiple txt files with generator in loop, using Python

Tags: python, loops, generator

The program calls the function and opens it only once at the loop. Do you have any solution about how I can make it call the function in the loop all the times? (I mean for every j)

```
def list_spectra(interpolated, txt):
    return (f for f in listdir(interpolated) if f.endswith("." + txt))

wl = []
fl = []
er = []

flux  = []
error = []

med_flux = []
med_err  = []

spectra_all = list_spectra("C:\\..my path here..\\interpolated","txt")
path = "C:\\..my path here..\\interpolated\\"

for j in range(0,len(wavelength)):
   for f in spectra_all:
        data = np.loadtxt(path+f)
        for ii in range(0,len(data)):

            wl = data[:,0]
            fl = data[:,1]
            er = data[:,2]    

            for i in range(0,len(wl)):
                if wl[i] == wavelength[j]:
                    flux.append(fl[i])
                    error.append(er[i])

    med_flux.append(np.median(flux))
    med_err.append(np.median(error))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this:

```
for j in range(0,len(wavelength)):
    spectra_all = list_spectra("C:\\..my path here..\\interpolated","txt")
    for f in spectra_all:
        data = np.loadtxt(path+f)
        # etc
```

Comment: Yeah! I mean this... :P Sometimes after hours of programming is difficult to see things that are clear.. Thank you very much!